# Three.js cannot export object with holes from blender

Tags: javascript, three.js, export, blender

I have problem with exporting object with holes from blender with three.js exporter. Here are some pictures. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is ur model in blender only made up of trigs and quads?

Comment: My partner made it but i am preatty sure its been made from cube

Comment: And the holes with cylinder

Comment: Ask your partner the question. FYI im 97.4% sure the blender importer doesnt support n-gons beside trig and quads.

Comment: I would but its 4:15 a.m. here :p I will post a comment here tomorrow. Thank you very much for your time :)